# Simple login randomly fails

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this very simple login system for an asp  website:

**On the Default.aspx page:**

```
protected void LoginClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"].ToString();
        string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"].ToString();
        string sanitizeUsername =uname.Text;
        string sanitizePassword = upass.Text;
        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sanitizeUsername +"   "+ sanitizePassword);

        if (sanitizePassword == password && sanitizeUsername == userName)
        {
           // System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Session is true......redirecting");
            Session["IsLogin"] = true;
            Response.Redirect("Page1.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Invalid Login");
        }
}
```

**On each of the other pages:**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (Session["IsLogin"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
```

**In the web.config file:**

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="UserName" value="aaa"/>
  <add key="Password" value="bbb"/>
</appSettings>
```

It works 10% of the times and I do not understand why. When it doesn't work nothing happen, the text entered in password and username fields disappears after the button click and thats all. I know that this can be done in many other ways for security reasons but I wonder why this is not working 100% of the times?

Comment: I assume you're just storing passwords in the config file as a temporary measure until you write the back end? Have you tried .Equals( ) instead?

Comment: Just tried. Same story, text disappear and nothing happen! Going mad about this.

Comment: Where does the problem produce itself? On your loginscreen or when you load another page? Could you load up your asp.net page aswell?

Comment: @svranken It happens in my browser during debug and also on the production server. I even tried from a different browser and after cleaning the browser too from history and cookies

Comment: Can u pls Degug on Page Load & tell what is the value of Session["IsLogin"] ? I think this is causing the issue.

Comment: Or Pls check if you enter any space character in UserName & Password textboxex...You can try string sanitizeUsername =uname.Text.Trim();

Comment: @saravanakumarr I checked the value of Session["IsLogin"]at Default page-load and it is null. I introduced the Trim() but is still the same even if I use simple username and password like "a" and "b". However thanks.

Comment: Can u put Try, Catch Block to see if any error is Occuring?

Comment: Maybe the session is blocked somehow in the web.config file?
Or maybe it resets after several miliseconds (try searching for those reasons)

Comment: Please debug the following line `Session["IsLogin"] = true;`   tell us the value of the session after the line.

Comment: @AmirOfir I think I found the problem. The login works only if the full URL is shown, I mean: If the url is ....://mysite.com the login page is shown but the login does not work. If the url is ....://mysite.com/Default.aspx then the login is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If some one is interest in the solution of the problem:

I noted that the login works only if the **full url is shown** including the page

```
http://mysite/Default.aspx
```

If the url does no-show the page name **../Default.aspx** the above login does not work.
The solution was to change the following line in the Default page:

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server"">
```

to

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" action="Default.aspx">
```

Thanks to an external resource, Kunal, for the hint.